# Resource contention with localtime in glibc, why?

Tags: c

I have found there is a resource contention when using localtime function in multi-threaded program.

But there is only one lock resource in the function? What might be the root cause for this bug?

Any suggestions or ideas on this issue is well appreciated.

code is as bellow, cut from glibc,

```
struct tm *
localtime (t)
     const time_t *t;
{
  return __tz_convert (t, 1, &_tmbuf);  //tmbuf temp variable
}

struct tm *
__tz_convert (const time_t *timer, int use_localtime, struct tm *tp)
{
  long int leap_correction;
  int leap_extra_secs;

  if (timer == NULL)
    {
      __set_errno (EINVAL);
      return NULL;
    }

  __libc_lock_lock (tzset_lock);

  /* Update internal database according to current TZ setting.
     POSIX.1 8.3.7.2 says that localtime_r is not required to set tzname.
     This is a good idea since this allows at least a bit more parallelism.  */
  tzset_internal (tp == &_tmbuf && use_localtime, 1);

  if (__use_tzfile)
    __tzfile_compute (*timer, use_localtime, &leap_correction,
              &leap_extra_secs, tp);
  else
    {
      if (! __offtime (timer, 0, tp))
    tp = NULL;
      else
    __tz_compute (*timer, tp, use_localtime);
      leap_correction = 0L;
      leap_extra_secs = 0;
    }

  if (tp)
    {
      if (! use_localtime)
    {
      tp->tm_isdst = 0;
      tp->tm_zone = "GMT";
      tp->tm_gmtoff = 0L;
    }

      if (__offtime (timer, tp->tm_gmtoff - leap_correction, tp))
        tp->tm_sec += leap_extra_secs;
      else
    tp = NULL;
    }

  __libc_lock_unlock (tzset_lock);

  return tp;
}
```

Comment: Are you actually calling "localtime()" often enough that synchronization is really an issue?  Is that wise?  Can you use an alternate API ?  [gettimeofday()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday) and/or [localtime_r()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime_r) come immediately to mind.

Comment: What bug? What issue? These functions are documented as dealing with global (static) data, glibc chose to use locking if you are multithreading rather than give you undefined behavior - that's pretty nice. Use the `_r` variants if you want reentrant versions.

Comment: To paulsm4: I moved to localtime_r, it seems no problem. But I don't know why gdb see stacks acquiring locks.

Comment: To Mat: "undefined behavior" I think localtime will end with wrong return value, as tmbuf is shared. But I don't know if this  "undefined behavior" will be lock issue.

Comment: **As the OP has stated that he solved the problem by using `localtime_r` instead, I'm voting to close this question.**

Comment: localtime_r delegates to __tz_convert, though: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=time/localtime.c;h=8684a8a9713fd4638270fd0b2390781f9b7bb102;hb=HEAD#l30 . The lock is not around _tmbuf, but aound tzset.c state: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=time/tzset.c;h=b51786704ae76ab4c74683dc2ccdac81aa9281cc;hb=HEAD#l579